# Box-shadow on mega drop-down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a little problem with a mega drop-down menu's box-shadow. Shadow should be visible above "second list item", and only the actual :hover li item should be above the dropdown box's shadow. I tried to set different variations of position and z-index properties, but i can't solve it.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>first list item
        <div id="sub">Sed id dolor nec odio cursus tincidunt. Ut tristique nulla odio, vitae ornare ligula tincidunt vitae. Sed cursus, erat eleifend bibendum auctor, quam diam pellentesque eros, ut consequat quam erat non ipsum. Cras ut ultrices leo. Aliquam blandit scelerisque sem at volutpat.</div>
    </li>
    <li>second list item</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0.2em;
}
ul li {
    background: orange;
    width: 175px;
    height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .25s ease;
    padding: 5px;
    margin 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul li #sub {
    background-color: #222;
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 32px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease;
    z-index: -20;
    padding: 0.7em;
    color: white;
    cursor: initial;
}
li:hover #sub {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R4xRJ/

How could i solve it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the submenu casts a shadow only on following `<li>` items, you can achieve your aim with the `+` css selctor. It will allow you to specify a negative z-index on the next `li` in the markup.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/R4xRJ/4/)**

you need to add

```
ul li:hover + li{
    z-index:-2;
}
```

and `z-index:-1;` to `ul li .sub`

*full CSS :*

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0.2em;
}
ul li {
    background: orange;
    width: 175px;
    height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .25s ease;
    padding: 5px;
    margin 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul li:hover + li{
    z-index:-2;
}
ul li .sub {
    background-color: #222;
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 32px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease;
    padding: 0.7em;
    color: white;
    cursor: initial;
    z-index:-1;
}
li:hover .sub {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

Comment: It's a little bit weird, when I add another submenu.
http://jsfiddle.net/R4xRJ/2/

Comment: @revotyx check my updated answer, found a better technique for your issue.

Comment: Awesome and so simple! Great idea!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding z-index to your hover...

```
li:hover #sub {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    z-index: 10;
```

}

Let me know whether or not this is what you were looking for...

Comment: Unfortunately not. In this case the shadow will be above the hovered list item...